# Correct Typing for HigherOrderComponents with recompose and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recompose

I'm currently trying to get recompose into my react codebase. Therefore I was trying to get some basic things working, and I got it working, but I'm not really sure, if this is the correct way recompose is intended to work.

So I have following Code:

```
interface Value {
  value: string
}

interface Loading {
  loading: boolean
}

const TestComponent = (props: Value) => <div>Value: {props.value}</div>
const LoadingComponent = () => <div>Loading ...</div>
```

So I have a TestComponent, which should display the Value provided in the props, and additionaly I have a LoadingComponent, which should be shown, when the loading props is set.

So I used the `branch` function of recompose

```
const withLoading = branch<Loading>(
  ({loading}) => loading, 
  renderComponent(LoadingComponent)
)
```

Now when I use `withLoading`on **any Component without props** I can set the loading prop on them.

```
const EnhancedCompWithLoading = withLoading(SomeCompWithoutProps)

render() {
  return <EnhancedCompWithLoading loading={this.state.loading} />
}
```

This works fine for me, the real problem starts when trying to use this with Components with props. When I try it like this:

```
const TestWithLoading = withLoading(TestComponent)

render() {
  return <TestWithLoading value="testVal" loading={this.state.loading} />
}
```

I get the ErrorMessage `TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Loading, any, any>>
& Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<Loading>'.`

So I looked the type definition in @types/recompose up. `branch<TOutter>` returns a `ComponentEnhancer<any,TOutter>`. Which I understand, I want to be able to provide `any` component, and the `<TOutter>` generic is so, that the resulting component knows about the needed props for the test function. Thats also working without additionals props.

However the TypeDefinition for the ComponentEnhancer looks like this (recompose 0.30.2):

```
interface ComponentEnhancer<TInner, TOutter> {
  (component: Component<TInner>): ComponentClass<TOutter>
}
```

So, the `ComponentEnhancer<any, Loading>` which I received from the previous `branch` function will return a `ComponentClass<Loading>`. However the `<TInner>` of the component I provide to the ComponentEnhancer will be thrown away and I cant use my `Value` props in the Enhanced Component.

So my Question here is, am i doing it just wrong, is there a better way to achieve this (with recompose). Or is it just a Bug in the TypeDeclaration, since changing the return of the `ComponentEnhancer` to `ComponentClass<TOutter & TInner>` fixes the whole thing for me.
Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `branch` and `recompose` but if this is just a typing issue we can fix it.

The problem is that the type for `branch` is not very good. If the intent is to forward the properties of the wrapped component to the HOC and add to the HOC the props typed explicitly to `branch` then a better type for the result would be:

```
type BetterComponentEnhancer<TOutter> = {
    <TInner>(component: React.ComponentType<TInner>): React.ComponentClass<TInner & TOutter>
}
```

With this type, this will work:

```
const withLoading = branch<Loading>(
    ({ loading }) => loading,
    renderComponent(LoadingComponent)
)as unknown as BetterComponentEnhancer<Loading>

type BetterComponentEnhancer<TOutter> = {
    <TInner>(component: React.ComponentType<TInner>): React.ComponentClass<TInner & TOutter>
}

const TestWithLoading = withLoading(TestComponent)

function render() {
    return <TestWithLoading value="testVal" loading={true} />
}
```

Comment: Hm, thats basically what i wrote in my last two sentences. When changing the return type to `ComponentClass<TInner & TOutter>` it will work. However I'm confused about the `as unknown` and why the `<TInner>` in Front of the BetterComponentEnhancer parameter

Comment: @Azael wops, my bad missed the last line in the question, I made `BetterComponentEnhancer` a generic function to get the type of the props  from the passed in component (TestComponent in this case) the `as unkown` is just a double type assertion as TS would not let me assert directly to `BetterComponentEnhancer`

Comment: So I tried your solution and it does work. Tooltip shows `React.ComponentClass<Value & Loading, any>`. For Solution it was `React.ComponentClass<any, any>`. Still bit confused bout the TS Syntax there.

I'll open an issue on the @types/recompose repo and will reference your solution.

Comment: @Azael The syntax is just a generic function signature, it's pretty standard TS. If you open an issue please post it here as well, I would be interested to see the team's response

Comment: Issue Link: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31885

Comment: Sadly I still have no answer to the Issue ... However i'm using your solution, so i marked your answer as correct.